# CupertinoPicker in BottomSheet 'data !=null' error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to place a **CupertinoPicker** in a **BottomSheet** which I am displaying with `showModalBottomSheet()`. This displays below error but the same code works fine if directly placed in the Main Layout(from where the modal is called).

error:

> A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
>   Failed assertion: line 285 pos 10: 'data != null'

Code:

```
Container(
      height: 150.00,
      child: CupertinoPicker(
        itemExtent: 30.00,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('a'),
          Text('b'),
          Text('c'),
          Text('d'),
          Text('e'),
        ],
        onSelectedItemChanged: (newIndex){
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Any ideas why wouldn't it work and any workaround for it?

[image]

Code for my BottomSheet layout is [here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/X2w0WM8o):

Answer (score 0):

When you close an overlay by clicking outside, it returns null value. I don't think that it's possible to override this behavior easily.

To return current value you need to add a button that will call *Navigator.pop* and you need to store current value of picker (inside state of widget).

[image: demo]

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    final data = await showModalBottomSheet<String>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return TextPicker(
          // Passing values
          values: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
        );
      },
    );

    if (data == null) {
      print('Null value returned');
    } else {
      print('Data is $data');
    }
  },
),

class TextPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> values;

  const TextPicker({Key key, @required this.values}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextPickerState createState() => _TextPickerState();
}

class _TextPickerState extends State<TextPicker> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 150.00,
          child: CupertinoPicker(
            itemExtent: 30.00,
            // Mapping values to widgets
            children: widget.values.map((v) => Text(v)).toList(),
            onSelectedItemChanged: (newIndex) {
              // Changing current index
              selectedIndex = newIndex;
            },
          ),
        ),
        CupertinoButton(
          child: Text('Ok'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Returning selected value
            Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.values[selectedIndex]);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem occurs during the initialization of BottomSheet, It directly opens with the error. I updated my post with an image.

Comment: @VipiNNegi The code that you attached is fine. You're passing null value to Text widget somewhere.

Comment: You were right, there was a different Text widget and passed it a null. So silly of me for not observing in the first place and blamed the Picker whole time. Thanks for pointing the issue out.